# Cannot load Google charts in Angular App

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

The below is an excerpt from the controller for the page I am loading (*in coffeescript - but should be straightforward to read*).  Once I have data from the server, I transform it into a json array of arrays.  onChartDataReady then runs, loads 3 files via the jsapi all with http status 200, but onGoogleReady is never called.

```
onDataLoad: (data) =>
    # @$scope.chartData = transformed data
    @onChartDataReady()

onChartDataReady: =>
    google.load 'visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] }
    google.setOnLoadCallback @onGoogleReady

onGoogleReady: =>
    chartTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable @$scope.chartData
    chartOptions = { title: 'Some silly data' }
    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart document.getElementById('chart_div')
    chart.draw chartTable, chartOptions
```

I copied the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) code from google and pasted that into a html file with no controller (i.e. angular is just loading the html) but it has the same problem - callback is not called.  When I open the file from my desktop it works fine.  Somehow angular is interfering with the google callback and I do not know how to troubleshoot.

Any pointers would be very helpful!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to an odd behavior in the google loader.  Try passing the callback inline with the `google.load` call instead of calling `google.setOnLoadCallback`.  The javascript would look like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'], callback: <callback function> });
```

I'm not a coffescript expert, but I think this is the syntax you would use:

```
google.load 'visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'], callback: @onGoogleReady }
```

Comment: Actually, the problem turned out to be that I **had** to bootstrap angular manually using the `setOnLoadCallback()` function rather than loading from the ng-app directive.